# Getting error in GDCprepare fuction when using TCGAbiolinks package

Tags: r

I am using TCGAbiolinks package. I have run this code:

```
coadquery <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-COAD", 
                      data.category = "Transcriptome Profiling",
                      data.type ="Gene Expression Quantification",
                      workflow.type ="STAR - Counts", legacy = F,
                      experimental.strategy ="RNA-Seq") 

GDCdownload(query = coadquery, method = "api")
      coadprpr <- GDCprepare(coadquery, summarizedExperiment = T)
```

but when I run GDCprepare function it gives me error:

> |==================================================|100%
> Completed after 12 m
>
> Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`: ! Can't subset columns past the
> end. i Locations 2, 3, and 4 don't exist. i There is only 1 column.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. There were
> 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)